# Exporting, externally modifying then re-importing data with MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access, export, import

I'm working with a client who has a large legacy MS Access 'application' with tens of database tables. As it stands, only 1 person can update the database at a time as it is non-distributed; standalone on a single workstation. Given the size and complexity of the MS Access application, we can't completely rewrite it - so the client has asked us to make certain tables updatable via a web app, importing and exporting the data at the start and end of the update phase.

We've been tasked with developing the following workflow:

- Export relevant data from necessary Access tables in an intermediary format (CSV, XML, etc) at the start of the data update process
- Import data into a web application powered by MySQL
- For a fixed period, allow multiple users to simultaneously update the data via the web app
- At the end of the data update process, export the data from MySQL in an intermediary format
- Import data back into MS Access

However, I can't find an appropriate mechanism to enable the last stage. No Access import option seems to allow you to update existing records as well as add new ones - you can import the data into a new table, as well as append new records to an existing table, but not update existing records based on primary key. As Access puts it in all its `Import` options...

```
Changes made to the source data will not be reflected in the database
```

Have I missed something with one of the import options? What other approaches might there be?

Comment: Can't you first do an update, then do an append?

Comment: How do you mean "do an update"?

Comment: I wasn't sure if your problem was that you were looking for a single import step, or if you did not know how to do a record update.  You can not Update through the import dialog.  I'll put a suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Perfect, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, in this scenario, I've broken the import/update into several steps

1. Append the data into an empty "temp" table
2. Create/run an update query, joining the target and source/temp tables
3. Create/run an append query, left-outer-joining target and source/temp tables (with target key=null)
4. (optional) append the temp table to a history table
5. Truncate the temp table

The steps can easily be automated with macros.